# how to install Ubuntu on oem Win 8

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I have an ASUS Q500A 64bit notebook with oem installed Windows 8. I am preparing to install Ubuntu 13.04 to dual boot. 
Any basic install advice would be nice, will Win8 secure boot, uefi, interfere and how can I get around it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say go into your BIOS settings (by mashing the "F" keys, or press the right one if you know which to press). then disable secure boot. then also you should switch from UEFI boot to the other option (maybe "legacy" or "CSM" depending on your motherboard). make sure to set cd or usb to be higher priority on the boot settings (depending on whether you are going to boot from cd or usb). save and exit. you can try to install ubuntu when it comes up, but i am going to disappoint you here: you most likely wont be able to dual boot. it will probably not detect windows 8 in the installer. this is what happened to myself, and i dont know a way to get around it. it may be different on yours but im just warning you. thats all you need to know probably.
hope this helps